# Securimage Image Style

Tags: php, captcha

I'll make this quick. Problem is that I can't make Securimage display a captcha image looking like this:
http://news.thomasnet.com/securimage/securimage_show.php

No matter what I do, or which settings I change, it's always looking something like this:
http://ecogridbornholm.dk/wp-content/plugins/si-captcha-for-wordpress/captcha/securimage_show.php

It doesn't really compliment my design and it's also a lot harder to read. Personally, I think the first is sufficient, protection-wise.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Also, it should be said that I think the first "style" is predefined somewhere as I've seen it on a lot of sites, so I'm sure it isn't anything customized.

Comment: What are your current settings?

Comment: I've removed all custom settings in my frustration, and now running default.. Now I'm reviewing the Securimage class to see if I can find a clue.. Haven't found anything yet though.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the first example is just an old version.. Do you know if this is the case?

Comment: I'm not too sure since I haven't used it myself, but have you updated your version? Are you using the latest version from the project's Github page, [located here](https://github.com/dapphp/securimage)? The images on the [project's website](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/try-securimage/) and your image look a bit different.

Comment: I was using the latest. Now I just tried an old version from 2009 that I know should show the image I want it to.. This is really weird. Take a look at this: http://www.webdevstuff.com/163/free-php-captcha-from-securimage.html